# Could single-electron qubits be compressed by 'a force' in an effort to increase the computer's processing power per volume, sorta like nuclear pasta?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-information

I have been studying this for an entire day now as a layman *(having just woken up from my previous day of studying on the internet and with a bit of help from GPT-3)* like, that's almost all I did all day, and **I was hoping an expert could tell me if my idea of "compressed single-electron qubit arrays" would have any self-defeating flaws that make such a theoretical technology impossible.**

My idea was that perhaps the very physical limit of computer miniaturization might be technically found in single electron qubit arrays, *(as opposed to photon arrays since it seems to me currently that electrons simply last far longer as massive particles)*, and since these electrons are merely point particles, perhaps it is possible to compact these electron arrays with something like a ridiculously strong magnetic field, to create a far more compact and far more intricate qubit array made of matter vaguely similar to.. say.. "electron pasta"? *-Not necessarily solid electron pasta just, 'far smaller than normal electron density per volume'.*

**Would there be anything that necessarily makes such a device impossible or infeasible *(besides energy costs?)* Perhaps some tiny detail I as a layman would never even hear about??** I don't assume quantum tunneling would have much of an effect given the strength of the magnetic fields, but then I haven't spent the last 40 years studying electron physics either so, here I am

*Thanks in advance.*